# Using Main from a class library instead of the program

Tags: c#, assemblies

I have numerous projects that all contain the exact same boilerplate code inside of the main function. They all reference the same assembly (which is the one providing a majority of the functionality). This assembly is not referenced by anybody except for the ones who use this same boilerplate main code.

Is it possible to have a Main function inside of a class within the assembly and use it within the program referencing the assembly instead of a class within the current assembly? I would prefer to not even write a Main function within the programs if I can.

EDIT: I want the Main inside of the referenced assembly to BE the entry point.

Comment: It must be the .exe assembly.  Solve your problem by providing a Main() method that just calls whatever other 'main' you want to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot skip the static `Main` function in your executable assemblies because that's the entry point but you could perfectly fine define a method in this assembly with the same signature that will be invoked from the Main methods of all projects that need this boilerplate code.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SomeClass.SomeMethodToDoBoilerplate(args);
    SomeSpecificMethods();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want the Main inside of the referenced assembly to BE the entry point.

Comment: @Jonathan Sternberg, no, as I said in my answer that's not possible. An assembly which is compiled with target:exe or target:winexe must have a static Main function or you won't be able to compile it at all.